# extract specific columns values from a csv python 3

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, file, csv

hi I have a csv file and I need extract specific columns values from this file using Python 3.

Here is my code:

```
from csv import reader

with open('', "/Users/tinasosiak/Documents/Tender1copy.csv") as output, open("/Users/tinasosiak/Documents/Tender1.csv", newlines='') as input:
    for row in reader("/Users/tinasosiak/Documents/Tender1.csv"):
        print(row[2], file="/Users/tinasosiak/Documents/Tender1copy.csv")
```

The csv file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FROUZ.png)

when I run my pogram I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/Users/tinasosiak/Documents/word_cloud/why.py", line 3, in 
>           with open('', "/Users/tinasosiak/Documents/Tender1copy.csv") as output, open("/Users/tinasosiak/Documents/Tender1.csv",
>   newlines='') as input:
>       ValueError: invalid mode: '/Users/tinasosiak/Documents/Tender1copy.csv'

Comment: Your error is pretty clear `open()` 2 position args is meant to be, `open(<name>, <mode>)`  see the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#open. You should read the `csv` documentation, `reader()` takes a file object, e.g. `input` - not a filename.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that I am answering here, but I have not enough reputation to comment your question.

Note firstly that ValueError sygnalizes that you have applied wrong mode to open the file (write("w")/read("r")/append("a")). In your code you have applied mode:

```
'/Users/tinasosiak/Documents/Tender1copy.csv'
```

And it won't work of course. It should be for example

```
with open("/Users/tinasosiak/Documents/Tender1copy.csv", 'rb') as output,
```

Comment: Looks like OP wants that file `as output` - so maybe open it for writing.